# Does there always exist an algebraic integer in a number field whose discriminant divides its norm?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $n$ over the rationals. Under what conditions does there exist an algebraic integer $\alpha $ in $K$ such that the discriminant of $\alpha$ divides the norm of $\alpha$?

Comment: By the discriminant of $\alpha$ do you mean $\mathrm{disc}(\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q)$ ? If so, then doesnt any integer $\alpha\in\mathbb Z$ satisfy this?

Comment: I guess we want constrain ourselves to $\alpha$ such that $K=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. In other word, to the case where $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ has a finite index in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: Thank you both for thinking about this. We would want $\alpha $ to generate $K$. Also, if $\alpha $ is a unit that generates $K$, then $N(\alpha ) = \pm 1$ but not necessarily D(\alpha ), discriminant of the minimum polynomial of $\alpha $. When $n = 2, 3$, there is always such an $\alpha $ but I'm still not sure about $n \geq 4$.

Comment: Perhaps my last comment was somewhat miss-leading since I meant so say something slightly different about $n = 3$. This deals with a conjecture that I can't prove and the context of the question is found in Remark 4.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.10060.pdf

Comment: The bounty didn't help. May be you can try your luck at MathOverflow?

Comment: Thank very much Jyrki ! I think I will.

Comment: I have now re-asked this question on MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312131/

Answer (score 1):

I crossed-posted this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312131/) as it was unanswered after two weeks and held a bounty. The question was then answered there.